# Follow back functionality

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Twitter like application where `users` can follow each other through a `Connection` model. In a table which lists all people who follow the `@user` I'd like to implement a link to `Follow Back`. Can I do this with a link or do I have to do this with forms and just display the buttons? How do I setup the changesets for these forms?

**web/models/user.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  use Arc.Ecto.Model

  schema "users" do
    field :last_name, :string

    has_many :follower_connections, MyApp.Connection, foreign_key: :followee_id
    has_many :followers, through: [:follower_connections, :follower]
[...]
```

**web/models/connection.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Connection do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "connections" do
    belongs_to :follower, MyApp.User
    belongs_to :followee, MyApp.User
[...]
```

**web/controllers/user_controller.ex**

```elixir
[...]
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  user = 
    Repo.get!(User, id) 
    |> Repo.preload([:followers, :follower_connections])

  conn
  |> assign(:user, user)
  |> render("show.html")
end
[...]
```

**web/templates/user/show.html.eex**

```html
[...]
<table>
  <tbody>
<%= for connection <- @user.follower_connections do %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= link connection.follower.last_name %></td>
      <td>
        <%= link ???????? "Follow Back" %>
      </td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
[...]
```

The `link ????????` part is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to an action implementing follow back like this:

```
link "Follow back", to: user_path(@conn, :follow_back, user_id, [])
```

The header will be something like this:

```
def follow_back(conn, %{"id" => id})
```

In your router:

```
get "/follow_back/:id", UserController, :follow_back
```

This solution skips the changesets at all. If you want custom validation on the data there is a great post on using `embedded_schema` for forms that aren't directly persisted to the database: http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/05/ectos-insert_all-and-schemaless-queries/

The docs on html link are here: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Link.html
The tutorial on routing: http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/routing
and tutorial on controllers: http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/controllers

Comment: Wouldn't a form which uses connect#create not be a more RESTful way?

Comment: It totally would. The only thing you need to change in the above code to make it happen is to add `method: :post`. It will generate the form with a button that you need. `link "Follow back", to: user_path(@conn, :follow_back, user_id, []), method: :post`. (it requires that JS is enabled though).